# how I have two sessons with two different lifetime?

Tags: laravel

If change Laravel lifetime sessions in `.env` file it works for all sessions. How can I determine the lifetimes of every session separately?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the config on the fly in your `AppServiceProvider.php` method register

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //you can make call to a db..
            $lifetime = 999;
            //then set the session lifetime like this
            config(['session.lifetime'=>$lifetime]); 
        }
 }
```